# sphere acts weird while changing its worldPosition

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, parent

I have an empty and I have set a sphere as its child. When I change the empty's worldPosition(via right-clicking with mouse) the sphere teleports to entirely different location. The strange thing is that when I print the sphere's coordinates it is exactly the same as the empty's and the mouse cursor's. Any ideas?

Here is the module I wrote.

```
#Import the bge library.
import bge

#Make the mouse cursor visible during game running time.
bge.render.showMouse(True)

#Set the current game scene and python controller to variables.
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

#The function "initialization" is responsible for setting all scene objects, object sensors and object actuators to variables.
#These variables are created into the function but are for global use. Their names are the names of the objects/sensors/actuators in blender.
def initialization():
    for k in scene.objects:
        exec("globals()[\"%s\"]=scene.objects[\"%s\"]"%(k,k))
    for k in ground.sensors:
        exec("globals()[\"%s\"]=ground.sensors[\"%s\"]"%(k,k))
    for k in cont.actuators:
        exec("globals()[\"%s\"]=cont.actuators[\"%s\"]"%(k,k))

def mouse_2D_coor():
    global mX, mY
    mouse_pos = bge.logic.mouse.position
    #Cramp the coordinates to what the camera sees. (0, 0) at the top left corner and (1, 1) at the bottom right corner.
    mX = max(0.0,min(1.0,mouse_pos[0]))
    mY = max(0.0,min(1.0,mouse_pos[1]))
    #print ("Mouse coor :",mX,mY)

def empty_to_pos():
    cursor_empty.worldPosition = (mop.position[0],mop.position[1],cursor_empty.worldPosition.z)

initialization()
#print (mop.hitPosition)
if (right_click.positive):
    empty_to_pos()
    print (cursor_empty.worldPosition)
    print ("Mouse",mop.position)
    print ("sphere",sphere.worldPosition)

print ("I reached the end of track.py")
```

Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35864)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from the blenderartist's forum where the user agoose77 wrote

> You need to use

```
mop.hitPosition
```

> . The position attribute of the base class of KX_MouseFocusSensor,
>   SCA_MouseSensor, returns the pixel position of the mouse, which can
>   reach a value in the thousands.

And it worked.